# counting appearances of a specific word in a .txt file in a directory

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that will allow me to count the appearances of a specific word in each file in a given directory. Looking to do this in python. I am somewhat at a loss.

Comment: Have you heard of `find`?

Comment: `grep -c 'somestring' somedir/*`?

Comment: If you are doing this in Python, what have you tried?

Comment: There are a lot of files, so I don't want to control+find for each one. I am looking to print a dictionary with the name of the file and the number of occurrences of a given word.

Comment: If you just want to print out the matches, this can be achieved pretty easily with some command line tools such as `grep` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/count-total-number-of-occurrences-using-grep)

or `find` (the command line utility, not the shortcut!)

Answer (score 0):

In file.py

```py
import os
files_and_directories = os.listdir("./files/")
prefix = './files/' 
iterator = 0
for file in files_and_directories: 
    with open(f'{prefix}/{file}', 'r') as f: 
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                if word == "Line":
                    print(word)
                    iterator += 1

print(iterator)



Of course, change the 'if word == "Line"' you whatever you want.
```

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that allows me to look for a specific word, not print all words and their frequencies. Can you tell me about the prefix variable and the with open command? I follow everything else I think.

Comment: the prefix variable is the folder name containing the files.
the with open command automatically closes the folder after you finish using it.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

This approach returns a dictionary with an entry for each text file in the folder specified by `path`, where the keys are the filenames and the values are dictionaries with words as keys and counts as values.

```
import os
from collections import Counter

def fun(path):
    res = {}
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
                words = f.read().split()
            res[filename] = dict(Counter(words))
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **glob** and the code below to create a dict containing the filenames as keys and the word appearances counts:

```
from glob import glob

word = 'apple'
result = {}
for filename in glob('./*.txt'):
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    result[filename] = len([w for w in f.read().replace('\n', ' ').split(' ') if w == word])
```

*Change the value of word variable as you wish*

So, if there are two txt files in the current folder with contents:

file1.txt

```
apple fruit apple
```

and

file2.txt

```
apple fruit orange
```

The **result** dict will be:

```
{'./file2.txt': 1, './file1.txt': 2}
```

Comment: My files have a lot of words, so I'd really like to just return the word I am querying about

Comment: Editing to fit your goal...